# Is it grammatically correct to use 'Haven't had to '?

Tags: modal-verbs

"We haven't had to invoke any supposed advantages of Fertile Crescent people themselves".

In this sentence, the modal 'have to' is followed by the helping verb 'have not'. Can you use a modal along with a helping verb or this is an exception ? Also,would it be correct to use 'have to' instead of 'had to'

Comment: It's perfectly correct, and _haven't have to_ would be wrong.

Comment: If you find it confusing to have two consecutive uses of ***to have*** with completely different syntax / meaning, you could always rephrase to *We haven't **needed to** invoke...* But note that native speakers won't see anything remotely odd about the usage as cited. In any case, for many native speakers, there are actually ***two different verbs*** here (many/most of us would pronounce the second verb as ***hat*** rather than ***had*** here, effectively *because* it's a "different verb").

Comment: I haven't had to answer a question like this before, but, yes. :)